# Error in installIing packages tidytext - R

Tags: r, tidytext

I tried to install package tidytext but got the following error:

```
install.packages("tidytext")
Installing package into ‘\\dcn4pfsh404/home_8/TUT/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/tidytext_0.1.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2755455 bytes (2.6 MB)
downloaded 2.6 MB

Error in install.packages : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone help me understand what I am missing? Thanks

Comment: First try this command `install.packages(c("mnormt", "psych", "SnowballC", "hunspell", "broom", "tokenizers", "janeaustenr"))` and then `install.packages("tidytext")`. Does it works ?

Comment: I installed snowball and janeaustenr successfully before but when I ran install.packages(c("mnormt", "psych", "SnowballC", "hunspell", "broom", "tokenizers", "janeaustenr")) it gave me the same error.

Comment: Try with one package at a time.

Comment: I tried one at a time and except for broom, all the others were installed successfully. However, after each package is installed (either successfully or not), the following error appeared and I had to start a new R session: "R session aborted.
R encountered a fatal error.
the session was terminated"

Comment: When installing broom, I had the same error as tidytext: "Error in install.packages : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Answer (score 7):

Marco Sandri's answer worked for me when I was facing the same problem. First try this command:

```
install.packages(c("mnormt", "psych", "SnowballC", "hunspell", 
                   "broom", "tokenizers", "janeaustenr"))
```

And then:

```
install.packages("tidytext")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue installing tidytext. I found this was due to tokenizer failing to install.

After a lot of searching, the solution was installing the missing the Xcode command line package onto my Mac. Xcode is a free package but not a default for Macs.

Instructions on uploading Xcode can be found at:

http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

After installing Xcode and running:
install.packages("tidytext")

The problem was solved.

Answer (score -2):

for me it's showing :

> install.packages("tidytext")
>   WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but are not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

*but finally, it's worked you have to just check your version compatibility.*